# Show/hide an element within one list item, not all of them

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, show-hide

I've generated a dynamic list of comments on a post from my server in Vue, and would now like a 'reply' button to appear on each comment that when clicked opens a textarea underneath it and is linked to that comment. However, my hacky solution meant that clicking on it opened **all** of the comments' text boxes, not just one.

How can I target each comment individually with a show/hide function in Vue?

I know why my solution isn't working—but I don't know where to start making a function that targets the specific comment on clicking it.

**Template (HTML)**

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.data.id">
        <div>User details</div>
        <div>Comment content</div>
        <div>
            <span>
                <a v-on:click="hideReply = !hideReply">Reply</a>
            </span>
        </div>

        <form v-if="hideReply">
            <textarea>Reply text box</textarea>
            <button>Reply button</button>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>Another comment in the list...</li>
    <li>Another comment in the list...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

**Script (JS)**

```
export default {
    name: 'Post',
    components: {},
    data () {
        return{
            hideReply: false,
            comment: undefined,
            comments: undefined
        }
    },
    async created () {
        // code to bring in my comments from server
    },
    methods: {
        betterShowHideFunction () {
            // where do i start
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of using boolean, keep track of the id of which textarea should be opened, for example `<form v-if="hideReply === comment.data.id">`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused by this — what else would I need to add to make it work?

Comment: I just don't know where in the if v-on:click part I can link it to the comment ID.

Comment: try v-on:click="hideReply = comment.data.id"

Answer (score 0):

Add a **show** property on each comment and use that for showing/hiding each individual comment

```
<form v-if="comment.show">
```

Change the var accordingly

```
<a v-on:click="comment.show = !comment.show">Reply</a>
```

Comment: is anything else needed to make this work, and how do I define the show property?

Comment: You should use map on the comments array this.comments = comments.map( item => { item.show = true; return item} )